# How to upload file to s3 in swift using accelerated endpoint

Tags: swift, aws-sdk

I want to upload file to s3 using [aws swift sdk](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/main/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferUtility.h)

I registered awsTransferUtility like this

```swift
// in app delegate

func application(
       _ application: UIApplication,
       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [
              UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any
              ]?) -> Bool {

        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.APSoutheast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

        AWSS3TransferUtility.register(
              with: configuration, 
              forKey: "east1"
       )

}
```

In my function I called transfer utility like this

```swift
let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: endpoint.rawValue)!
        
        
        transferUtility.uploadData(
               data,
               bucket: bucket,
               key: uploadPath,
               contentType: "text/plain",
               expression: expression, completionHandler: 
               completionHandler).continueWith {
            (task) -> AnyObject? in
            guard task.error == nil else {debugPrint(task.error!); return nil}
            if let result = task.result {
                debugPrint(result)
            }
            return nil
        }
```

This works but it is uploading using a standard endpoint. How can I make it upload using the accelerated endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you init the transfer utility object, in app delegate, you can add the option to use accelerated endpoint

```
let s3config = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()
s3config.isAccelerateModeEnabled = true

AWSS3TransferUtility.register(
              with: configuration,
              transferUtilityConfiguration: s3config,
              forKey: "east1"
       )
```

then you can call upload normally, it will use the accelerated endpoint